# Namespace "Microsoft.Web/sites/hybridConnectionNamespaces" missing?

Tags: azure-bicep

We are using Visual Studio Code and the Bicep plugin.

When we define a new hybrid connection using "Microsoft.Web/sites/hybridConnectionNamespaces/relays@2022-09-01" we want to use the parent property. But we got a BCP036 error expecting a reference to an "Microsoft.Web/sites/hybridConnectionNamespaces" instance. But we cannot find any documentation regarding this resource. Any suggestions?

Comment: you may want to use name attribute of bicep instead of parrent property.
so name should have two '/' for e.g.  '${appServiceName}/${hcNamespace}/${hcName}'

If you are using parent property then it could use value as {appServiceName}/${hcNamespace}

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question... Trying to do what you've described in bicep, does indeed cause problems with the parenting. Where there aren't types available or if there's something overly complex in the Resource Provider then falling back to **setting the parent lineage seperated with '/' just in the Resource Name** would be my advice.

I took an existing app and enabled HybridConnections and then went back to the resource group to see what's changed. (This is my go-to for trying to capture what's going on).
Unfortunately it's not a resource that can have the ARM template exported;

[image]

Next step is to stay in the Azure Portal,enable browser developer tools, switch to the network tab and then add a new HybridConnection to see what API calls are being sent out. Often this is a great way to see what's happening with the resource providers when things aren't documented.

[image]
[image]

From here i can see exactly the Resource Name notation that i'll need to use in my bicep resource in order to set the name parent properly, and when i check the Payload i can see exactly what properties are being sent.